# Point Karaf paxexam to a custom location

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, karaf, pax-exam

Hi is there a way to point the paxexam karaf to a custom location i.e a karaf installation in your file system

```
return new Option[] {
                karafDistributionConfiguration().frameworkUrl(maven().groupId("org.apache.karaf").artifactId("apache-karaf")
                        .type("zip").versionAsInProject())
                .unpackDirectory(new File("target/paxexam/unpack/"))
                .useDeployFolder(false),
                systemProperty("Orcale.DbHandler").value(dbHandler.getURL()),
                KarafDistributionOption.debugConfiguration("8898", true),
                bootClasspathLibrary(oracleLib),
                configureConsole().ignoreLocalConsole(),
                logLevel(LogLevel.INFO),
                keepRuntimeFolder(),

        };
```

The above code points to a zip in maven repo instead of that can i point it to a local karaf folder  in file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, the karaf container support only tar.gz or zip

see: https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.exam2/blob/master/containers/pax-exam-container-karaf/src/main/java/org/ops4j/pax/exam/karaf/container/internal/ArchiveExtractor.java

You have to create your own test container if you want to clone an existing folder

Edit:
Open issue in Pax-Exam : https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXEXAM-614

Comment: Creating my own test container? could you provide me with some details.

Comment: you're right, but i didn't find any code on this feature in the current version of PaxExam. Moreover, this issue has been transfered into the pax-exam jira, and is still open. I can't be wrong, the code on this lib is really complex :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help do you have a pax exam jira link.